# wordpress ajax load more with multi-category filter

Tags: php, wordpress

I followed the tutorial from [here](https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/ajax-load-more-with-filters.html#comment-2505). But I want to make it to filter multi categories/taxonomies with ajax load more.

After I set the filter, when I click load more it will show all category posts, not the category that is checked

Is there anyway to show the categories checked when load more.

[Filter checkboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tO8Ai.jpg)

Index.PHP

```
<form id="misha_filters" action="#">
      <div class="checkbox-wrap">
        <input type="checkbox" id="fi1-all" name="categoryfilter-all" value="all" checked>
        <label for="fi1-all" class="cat-all">
          <?php
            $args = array(
              'posts_per_page' => -1,
              'post_status' => 'publish',
              'category' => '-1', // except uncategorized
            );
            $posts_array = get_posts( $args );
            $total_post = count($posts_array);
          ?>
          All (<?php echo $total_post ?>)
          <span class="icon-check"><?php include 'inc/vectors/check-for-checkbox-white.svg' ?></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <?php
            if( $terms = get_terms( 'category', 'orderby=name' ) ) :
          $a = 0;
                foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
          $a++;
          if ( $term->slug !== 'uncategorized' ) :
        ?>
          <div class="checkbox-wrap">
            <input type="checkbox" id="fi1-<?php echo $a ?>" name="categoryfilter-<?php echo $a ?>" value="<?php echo $term->term_id ?>">
            <label for="fi1-<?php echo $a ?>" class="cat-<?php echo $term->slug ?>">
              <?php echo $term->name ?> (<?php echo $term->count; ?>)
              <span class="icon-check"><?php include 'inc/vectors/check-for-checkbox-white.svg' ?></span>
            </label>
          </div>
      <?php
          endif;
                endforeach;
            endif;
        ?>
```

function.php

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'misha_script_and_styles');

function misha_script_and_styles() {

    global $wp_query;


    wp_register_script( 'misha_scripts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/inc/script-filter-loadmore.js', array('jquery') );



    wp_localize_script( 'misha_scripts', 'misha_loadmore_params', array(
        'ajaxurl' => site_url() . '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', 
        'posts' => json_encode( $wp_query->query_vars ), 
        'current_page' => $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] ? $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] : 1,
        'max_page' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
    ) );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'misha_scripts' );
}







add_action('wp_ajax_loadmorebutton', 'misha_loadmore_ajax_handler');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_loadmorebutton', 'misha_loadmore_ajax_handler');

function misha_loadmore_ajax_handler(){


    $taxonomy = 'category';
    $taxonomy_terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, array(
                                            'hide_empty' => 0,
                                            'fields' => 'ids',
                                            'exclude' => get_cat_ID('uncategorized'),
                                        ));
    $form_filter_checkboxes = array($_POST['categoryfilter-1'], $_POST['categoryfilter-2'],
                                                                    $_POST['categoryfilter-3'], $_POST['categoryfilter-4'],
                                                                    $_POST['categoryfilter-5'], $_POST['categoryfilter-6'],
                                                                    $_POST['categoryfilter-7']); 



    $params = json_decode( stripslashes( $_POST['query'] ), true ); 
    $params['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 1; 
    $params['post_status'] = 'publish';
    $params['posts_per_page'] = '3';
    $params['tax_query'] =  array(
                                                        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                                                        'field' => 'id',
                                                        'terms' => $form_filter_checkboxes,
                                                    )
                                                ;


    query_posts( $params );
    global $wp_query;

    if( have_posts() ) :
        while( have_posts() ): the_post();
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/post-type-content', get_post_format() );
        endwhile;
    endif;
    die; 
}



add_action('wp_ajax_mishafilter', 'misha_filter_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_mishafilter', 'misha_filter_function');

function misha_filter_function(){



    $params = array(
        'orderby' => 'date', 
        'order' => 'DESC', 
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 2
    );




    $taxonomy = 'category';
    $taxonomy_terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, array(
                                            'hide_empty' => 0,
                                            'fields' => 'ids',
                                            'exclude' => get_cat_ID('uncategorized'),
                                        ));
    $form_filter_checkboxes = array($_POST['categoryfilter-1'], $_POST['categoryfilter-2'],
                                                                    $_POST['categoryfilter-3'], $_POST['categoryfilter-4'],
                                                                    $_POST['categoryfilter-5'], $_POST['categoryfilter-6'],
                                                                    $_POST['categoryfilter-7']);




    if ( $_POST['categoryfilter-all'] === 'all') :
        $params['tax_query'] = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $taxonomy_terms,
            )
        );
    else :
        $params['tax_query'] = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $form_filter_checkboxes,
            )
        );
    endif;




    query_posts( $params );


    global $wp_query;
    if( have_posts() ) :

        ob_start(); 

        while( have_posts() ): the_post();
            echo $_POST['categoryfilter-all'];
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/post-type-content', get_post_format() );
        endwhile;

        $posts_html = ob_get_contents(); 
        ob_end_clean(); 
    else:
        $posts_html = '<p>Nothing found for your criteria.</p>';
    endif;




    echo json_encode( array(
        'posts' => serialize( $wp_query->query_vars ),
        'max_page' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'found_posts' => $wp_query->found_posts,
        'content' => $posts_html
    ) );

    die();
}
```

JS File

```
jQuery(function($){

    /*
     * Load More
     */
    $('#misha_loadmore').click(function(){

        $.ajax({
            url : misha_loadmore_params.ajaxurl, // AJAX handler
            data : {
                'action': 'loadmorebutton', // the parameter for admin-ajax.php
                'query': misha_loadmore_params.posts, // loop parameters passed by wp_localize_script()
                'page' : misha_loadmore_params.current_page // current page
            },
            type : 'POST',
            beforeSend : function ( xhr ) {
                $('#misha_loadmore').text('Loading...'); // some type of preloader
            },
            success : function( posts ){
                if( posts ) {

                    $('#misha_loadmore').text( 'More posts' );
                    $('#misha_posts_wrap').append( posts ); // insert new posts
                    misha_loadmore_params.current_page++;

                    if ( misha_loadmore_params.current_page == misha_loadmore_params.max_page )
                        $('#misha_loadmore').hide(); // if last page, HIDE the button
                } else {
                    $('#misha_loadmore').hide(); // if no data, HIDE the button as well
                }
            }
        });


        return false;
    });

    /*
     * Filter
     */
    $('#misha_filters').submit(function(){

        $.ajax({
            url : misha_loadmore_params.ajaxurl,
            data : $('#misha_filters').serialize(), // form data
            dataType : 'json', // this data type allows us to receive objects from the server
            type : 'POST',
            beforeSend : function(xhr){
                $('#misha_filters').find('button').text('Filtering...');
            },
            success : function( data ){

                // when filter applied:
                // set the current page to 1
                misha_loadmore_params.current_page = 1;

                // set the new query parameters
                misha_loadmore_params.posts = data.posts;

                // set the new max page parameter
                misha_loadmore_params.max_page = data.max_page;

                // change the button label back
                $('#misha_filters').find('button').text('Apply filter');

                // insert the posts to the container
                $('#misha_posts_wrap').html(data.content);

                // hide load more button, if there are not enough posts for the second page
                if ( data.max_page < 2 ) {
                    $('#misha_loadmore').hide();
                } else {
                    $('#misha_loadmore').show();
                }

            }
        });
        // do not submit the form
        return false;

    });

});
```

Comment: Your issue solved ? could you please provide the full code ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$params = json_decode( stripslashes( $_POST['query'] ), true );
```

The above line is not calling the filter query loop. That is why, you are not able to get the queried loop, set by misha_filter_function(){}.

**Update (Fixed):** Please check the update below.

The actual problem was

```
$_POST['query']
```

is returning not a JSON format data instead it's returning serialized form of data.
So that using json_encode doesn't make any sense. Simply change this line

```
$params = json_decode( stripslashes( $_POST['query'] ), true );
```

to this

```
$params = unserialize( stripslashes( $_POST['query']) );
```

Then it must work. All the best (y)

Comment: I aslo facing same issue how i can solve the issue?

Comment: Is that your issue solved ? Could you please provide the full code ? \

Comment: Yes, I had solved it.  Providing full code is not possible, you can ask your query. I will be happy to help.

Comment: I was also experience the same issue could you please send the full code with me on email ??

Comment: My issue is following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56611178/how-to-add-ajax-pagination-on-ajax-post-filter-result

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still have a problem, but here's my solution by simply change:

```
echo json_encode( array(
    'posts' => serialize( $wp_query->query_vars ),
    'max_page' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
    'found_posts' => $wp_query->found_posts,
    'content' => $posts_html
) );
```

TO

```
echo json_encode( array(
    'posts' => json_encode( $wp_query->query_vars ),
    'max_page' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
    'found_posts' => $wp_query->found_posts,
    'content' => $posts_html
) );
```

I just changed `serialize` to `json_encode` and this is the right way and you will get your terms posts!

You should not use unserialize the way Deepak did. It's very insecure. There's a red warning in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php), and you can easily find explanations on why it's dangerous by searching for PHP object injection.

Do yourself a favor and use json_encode/decode. It shouldn't make a difference since query_vars is a simple array.

Comment: Could You Please share Your Full Code ?